# python matrix average around single point

Tags: python, matrix

I have a preexisting algorithm that prints out a matrix of integers that represent topography to a particular file. If a single point cannot be averaged the algorithm replaces the integer with a string (let's call it `None`).

My goal is this.

Anywhere a `None` is I want to take the average of all immediate matrix neighbors and convert that from a float to an integer. See below...

```
|1    2    3|
|4  None   5|
|6    7    8|
```

In this case I want the average to be

```
(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8)/8 = 4.5 = 5
```

Any help on how to move forward would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in xrange(len(mat)):
  for j in xrange(len(mat[i])):
    continue if mat[i][j] is not None;
    mat[i][j] = (sum([mat[a][b] if mat[a][b] else 0
                     for a in xrange(max(0, i-1), min(i+1, len(mat))
                     for b in xrange(max(0, j-1), min(j+1, len(mat[i])))]) / 
                 sum([1 if mat[a][b] is not None else 0
                     for a in xrange(max(0, i-1), min(i+1, len(mat))
                     for b in xrange(max(0, j-1), min(j+1, len(mat[i])))]))
```

Comment: This is the way to go even if it would scale poorly with matrix size.

Comment: For some reason I cannot get this line to work....I keep getting syntax errors. Any suggestions??